# Why is my nth-of-type selector not working?

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

https://codepen.io/Yarwaa/pen/jpXqjL

I have the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button').click(function(){
    $('.row').append('<div class="col-4"><div class="text-container"><h1 class="heading">Something</h1></div></div>');
  });
});
```

```css
.text-container:nth-of-type(odd){
   background-color: green;
   color: yellow;
}
.text-container:nth-of-type(even){
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

What I want to make:

When I click on the button, I need to get `text-container` with `background-color: green` for odd numbers, and container with `background-color: yellow`.

The problem is: each container is considered like an odd number, and if I add another class to the `col-4` container and set background-color for this class, then it will remove all padding from columns and they will be very close to each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstand how `:nth-of-type()` works.

Each `.text-container` you add is `odd`.

`:nth-of-type()` count refers to nth-of-type **within any given context**, which in your case is `<div class="col-4">`. Within those, each of your `<div class="text-container">` is `:first-of-type`.

Here's what you probably need (all I changed is the CSS selectors):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    $('.row').append('<div class="col-4"><div class="text-container"><h1 class="heading">Something</h1></div></div>');
  });
});
```

```css
.row>div:nth-of-type(odd) .text-container {
  background-color: green;
  color: yellow;
}

.row>div:nth-of-type(even) .text-container {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click to add a div</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your text-containers are inside their own div, they're always the first of type. Try this for your JS instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button').click(function(){
    $('.row').append('<div class="col-4 text-container"><h1 class="heading">Something</h1></div>');
  });
});
```

then all your text-containers are siblings and it works!